# Windows 7 Serial adapter non-admin

Tags: serial

I have an old program (meaning I don't have the source) that uses a serial port.  I use a USB to serial adapter for the hardware connection.  This old program is expecting com port 1 to 8 that is set manually, not anyway detected.  It is possible that windows will set a com number outside of that range for the adapter.

I would like to allow a non-admin user to set the number, but so far I don't think that is possible.  Can I with a group policy change?  Or any other suggestion?  Thanks.